# Ionic Storage or Cache only?

Tags: ionic3, storage, documentation

I want to store some data, I'm using Ionic 3 and I saw the Storage class. Can I use it to store something and then retrive that having closed my app? Does it phisically save something on my device storage? Or is it a simple cache that vanishes when i close my app?

Comment: Yes, it "physically" saves it. Intangible though.

Answer (score 1):

It's physically saved, **but** the docs says

> When running in a native app context, Storage will prioritize using SQLite, as it's one of the most stable and widely used file-based databases, and avoids some of the pitfalls of things like localstorage and IndexedDB, such as the OS deciding to clear out such data in low disk-space situations.

so follow the docs at https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/ and install the `cordova-sqlite-storage` plugin to make the storage really persistent.